# Failed to load pdf, dompdf error -> PDF.js v0.8.787 (build: 58407cf) Message: InvalidPDFException

Tags: php, mysql, dompdf

Following is my code to display a pdf using dompdf but the error was failed to load pdf 
PDF.js v0.8.787 (build: 58407cf)
Message: InvalidPDFException

table name is acad_act and database name is pbas_db. Details of database connection is stored in db_connect.php. Any help would be appreciable

```
    <?php
            include('db_connect.php');
            require 'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

    $sqlinv="SELECT * FROM acad_act";
    $res_inv = mysql_query($sqlinv) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($sql3=mysql_fetch_array($res_inv)) {
            $inv_id = $sql3['User_id'];
            $date = $sql3['Year'];
            $cname = $sql3['Gen_Info_AQ'];
            $subtotal = $sql3['Gen_Info_NOC'];
            $disc = $sql3['Gen_Info_Place'];
            $subtotal2 = $sql3['Gen_Info_Duration'];
            $tax = $sql3['Gen_Info_SA'];
            $gtotal = $sql3['Gen_Info_Aqyear'];
    }

    $dompdf= new DOMPDF();

   $html .="<html>
        <head>
        <style>
    body {
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;
        border: 1px solid #333333;
    }
    tr {
        width: 100%;
    }
    td {
        border: 1px solid #333333;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        font-weight: normal!important;
    }
    </style>
    </head><body>";
    $html .="
    <table>
    <thead>
            <tr>
            <th class=''>Sr.</th>
            <th class=''>Particulars</th>
            <th class=''>Size</th>
            <th class=''>Quantity / Insertion</th>
            <th class=''>Rate</th>
            <th class=''>Amount</th>
            <th class=''>Amount 2</th>
            <th class=''>Amount 3</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>" . $inv_id . "</td>
            <td>" . $date . "</td>
            <td>" . $cname . "</td>
            <td>" . $subtotal . "</td>
            <td>" . $disc . "</td>
            <td>" . $subtotal2 . "</td>
            <td>" . $tax . "</td>
            <td>" . $gtotal . "</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>";

    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();

    $dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");

    exit(0);
    ?>
```

Comment: Instead of rendering to dompdf try just echoing the value of $html to make sure there are no issues. Or, alternately, save the PDF and open in a text viewer. Some non-PDF content could have been caught in the PDF output stream.

Comment: I tried echoing the content of $html, but it gives rise to an error
Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'An input file is required (i.e. input_file _GET variable).
DOMPDF_Exception: An input file is required (i.e. input_file _GET variable).

Comment: I have also tried displaying the content on the browser by simply using php and html. In that case data is displayed nicely without any error which means that the above error is not due to database connection, it must be due to localhost but can't get rid off this error..

Comment: That exception should only show if you are using the included quick-start script (dompdf.php).

Comment: i have only included dompdf_config.inc.php. Did you mean i should include dompdf.php?

Comment: You should *not* include dompdf.php. But something in your scripts is including it because the exception you see is produced if you run dompdf.php without specifying an input file.

Comment: Thanx for your concerned BrianS, but how can i get rid off this exception?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44978/discussion-between-brians-and-user3026618)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is due to pdf.js plugin installed in the browser. Instead of rendering the error the pdfjs shows an exception which doesn't display the error. Just remove the pdfjs plugin than you will be able to see the required error.